# Encode String URL in Java

Tags: java

I have this code below that encodes a URL before it is send over the wire (email):

```
private static String urlFor(HttpServletRequest request, String code, String email, boolean forgot) {
    try {
        URI url = forgot
            ? new URI(request.getScheme(), null, request.getServerName(), request.getServerPort(), createHtmlLink(),
                    "code="+code+"&email="+email+"&forgot=true", null)
            : new URI(request.getScheme(), null, request.getServerName(), request.getServerPort(), createHtmlLink(),
                    "code="+code+"&email="+email, null);
        String s = url.toString();
        return s;
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}  

/**
 * Create the part of the URL taking into consideration if 
 * its running on dev mode or production
 * 
 * @return
 */
public static String createHtmlLink(){
    if (GAEUtils.isGaeProd()){
        return "/index.html#ConfirmRegisterPage;";
    } else {
        return "/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#ConfirmRegisterPage;";
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that the generated email looks like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html%3Fgwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997%23ConfirmRegisterPage;?code=fdc12e195d&email=demo@email.com
```

The `?` mark and `#` symbol is replaced with `%3F` and `%23` where when the link is opened from the browser it will not open as it is incorrect.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Encode only the query parameters, not the path segemts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine the query-parts of the url and add the fragment as the correct parameter.

Something like this should work:

```
private static String urlFor(HttpServletRequest request, String code, String email, boolean forgot) {
    try {
        URI htmlLink = new URI(createHtmlLink());
        String query = htmlLink.getQuery();
        String fragment = htmlLink.getFragment();
        fragment += "code="+code+"&email="+email;
        if(forgot){
            fragment += "&forgot=true";
        }
        URI url = new URI(request.getScheme(), null, request.getServerName(), request.getServerPort(), htmlLink.getPath(),
                    query, fragment);
        String s = url.toString();
        return s;
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried your code but the output looks like this:

`http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997&code=4522ebee9f&email=demo@email.com#ConfirmRegisterPage;` it should be `http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#ConfirmRegisterPage;&code=4522ebee9f&email=demo@email.com`

Comment: @xybrek: Are you 100% sure about that? I am 90% sure that the "&code=...&email=..." should go in the query part and not in the fragment part, but if you are sure, just append the "&code..." to htmlLink.getFragment() instead of htmlLink.getQuery().

Comment: Yeah... as per Errai documentation:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ERRAI/Errai+UI+Navigation

Comment: Very well then. I have updated the code to fit that output (I assume you mean "#ConfirmRegisterPage;code=45..." and not "#ConfirmRegisterPage;&code=45...").

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Java API method [URLEncoder#encode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,java.lang.String%29). Encode the query parameters using the method.

A better API for doing this is the [UriBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html).